# Shift the position of each value to the next index In an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP.
 For example :

```
Array
(
    [3] => 6
    [2] => 4
    [1] => 2
    [4] => 8
    [6] => 12
)
```

I need to shift the position of each value to the next index.
ie, The desired output is

```
Array
(
    [3] => 12
    [2] => 6
    [1] => 4
    [4] => 2
    [6] => 8
)
```

I need to keep the keys unchanged and round shift the values.

Which is the simplest method to attain it?

What I already tried is

```
$lastValue = $array[array_keys($array)[4]];
$firstKey  = array_keys($array)[0];

for ($i=4; $i>0; $i--) {
$array[array_keys($array)[$i]] = $array[array_keys($array)[$i-1]];
   }

$array[$firstKey] = $lastValue;
print_r($array);
```

Comment: @GameO7er In that question, Requirement is to shift the position of key - value pair.
What I need is Round Shifts the values only.

Comment: _“Which is the simplest method to attain it?”_ - please don’t ask that kind of question, without showing any own attempts you made before asking.

Comment: I removed the flag after you edited your post. Welcome to SO and enjoy it dear friend :-) I just voted up your question so forgive me

Comment: @04FS Ok.. Just edited my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

php is so coool ^_^
part of the idea ~stolen~ taken from @Peters solution, sorry, mate :)

```
<?php

$array = 
[
    3 => 6,
    2 => 4,
    1 => 2,
    4 => 8,
    6 => 12,
];

$newArray = array_combine(array_keys($array), array_merge([array_pop($array)], $array));
var_dump($newArray);
```

[demo](https://www.tehplayground.com/xi91qRaSeeBsZIex)

Comment: I didn't have the chance to test my answer. But yours does the trick. I should've checked the function outputs. +1

Comment: @Peter, you the first!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a round shift on the value. [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5b8d7a42cad87f6999d3ccc6e997de548890ee3)

```
$array =
    [
        3 => 6,
        2 => 4,
        1 => 2,
        4 => 8,
        6 => 12,
    ];
$values = [null];
$keys = [];
foreach($array as $k => $v){
    $keys[] = $k;
    $values[] = $v;            
}
$values[0] = $v;
array_pop($values);
$result = array_combine($keys,$values);

print_r($result);
```